# Multiple UIs in one UI?

Tags: vue.js, user-interface

If I have multiple UIs for different **independent** apps (for example written in Vue), can I build a UI that can has a common title, settings etc. and can switch between those UIs? A **very** simple example for better understanding - a UI with a banner "Social Networks" that can switch between Facebook and Instagram (within the same UI, with same URL and same banner)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. It could go from using iframes to developping a shared component library, passing by using data CMS. Please clarify your idea so we can provide a better answer as this is a really wide question.

Comment: @Kapcash unfortunately that's as concrete as I can get, it's an idea my boss has and I'm not sure if and how it would be possible (hence the question)